# 'float' object is not callable in my game

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game in which a stopwatch is required, so i was searching that how i can add a stopwatch.
here is the code i tried:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time()

print(elapsed_time)
```

when i run this using pygame it shows

"'float' object is not callable"

File "C:\Users\shlok\Downloads\Programs(python)\tag.py", line 56, in redraw_window
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time()

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

I thought that is its saying that float object is not callable it means it has to be converted into integer so i tried using math.trunc() method but still it showing the same problem.
Any help will be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start_time is a float object, not a function. Remove `()` from your third line.

Comment: thank you, it is not showing the problem anymore but my seconds is not increasing

Comment: If it’s in a loop then it’s because you’re restating start_time every loop and calculated elapsed time based on that loop. Remove start_time outside to fix that.